# Setting adsize programmatically not working for NativeAdExpress

Tags: java, android, admob

My XML code for the ad is

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:adUnitId="YOUR_AD_ID"/>
```

I am setting the adsize programmatically using the following code

```
mAdView = (NativeExpressAdView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
int width = screenwidth - 16;
mAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize(width, 250));
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
   .addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE")
   .build();
mAdView.loadAd(request);
```

When I run, the app crashes with the error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.

It works fine when I try like this

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1072772517"
    app:adSize="320x250"/>
```

But I want to set the ad width dynamically

Comment: Try including `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in your `xml'  file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been solved when I added the NativeExpressAdView programmatically and removed from XML as follows.

```
mAdView = new NativeExpressAdView(this);
int width = screenwidth - 16;
mAdView.setAdSize(new AdSize(width, 250)); 
mAdView.setAdUnitId("myAdUnitId");

// Create an ad request.
AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

// Optionally populate the ad request builder.
adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);

// Add the NativeExpressAdView to the view hierarchy.
layout.addView(mAdView);

// Start loading the ad.
mAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am setting adsize dynamically and its working fine.
Below is my code.

```
private void setUpAndLoadNativeExpressAds() {
    // Use a Runnable to ensure that the RecyclerView has been laid out before setting the
    // ad size for the Native Express ad. This allows us to set the Native Express ad's
    // width to match the full width of the RecyclerView.
    mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final float scale = MainActivity.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            // Set the ad size and ad unit ID for each Native Express ad in the items list.
            for (int i = 0; i <= mRecyclerViewItems.size(); i += ITEMS_PER_AD) {
                adView = (NativeExpressAdView) mRecyclerViewItems.get(i);
                final CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.ad_card_view);
                final int adWidth = cardView.getWidth() - cardView.getPaddingLeft()
                        - cardView.getPaddingRight();
                AdSize adSize = new AdSize((int) (adWidth / scale), NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_HEIGHT);
                adView.setAdSize(adSize);
                adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
            }
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
         }
    });
}
```

May be you need to set add unit id before loading adds.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I had added the ad unit id in xml before. When I added the same programmatically, the crash is fixed but there is an error says **Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing**.